# for loop always displays a word per line instead of displaying what I want

Tags: bash, for-loop

```
#!/bin/bash
message="This message is so freaking long that I have to split it into two or more messages"
split=${#message}
array=( ${message:0:5} ${message:5:5} ${message:10:5} ${message:15:5} ${message:20:5})

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
echo "send me a message with \"$i\""
done
```

The output is like this:

```
send me a message with "This"
send me a message with "messa"
send me a message with "ge"
send me a message with "is"
send me a message with "so"
send me a message with "f"
send me a message with "reaki"
```

But I don't want that, I want it like this:

```
send me a message with "This "
send me a message with "messa"
send me a message with "ge is"
send me a message with "so fr"
send me a message with "eakin"
send me a message with "g lon"
send me a message with "g tha"
```

How should I fix it? I have googled but I still can't get it to work like what I want, I don't know if the `for loop` is incorrect or the `${message:x:x}` ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use more quotes please!

```
$ array=( "${message:0:5}" "${message:5:5}" "${message:10 :5}" "${message:15:5}" "${message:20:5}" )
$ for i in "${array[@]}"
> do
> echo "send me a message with \"$i\""
> done
send me a message with "This "
send me a message with "messa"
send me a message with "ge is"
send me a message with " so f"
send me a message with "reaki"
```

The whitespace in the words were causing them to be treated as separate elements in the array, which was causing the behaviour you observed. Enclosing each element in double quotes prevents this word splitting from happening.

Comment: @Lin no problem, you were almost there, in that you quoted the `"${array[@]}"` and the `$i`.